# Why didn't I get the gold badge for a review queue?

Tags: support, review-queues, badges

```
1 + 1 equals 2 and not 1
```

I completed my **Review | Triage (2,015 reviews)** for the second time and **Review | First Posts (1,006 reviews)** on the same day, but I received only one **Steward** badge.

Why does this happen?

Comment: `numberOfReviews >= 1000 ? 1 : 0` < 2

Comment: Still: Thank you for investing your time with the review queues! Even without another badge, your work is appreciated!

Comment: Common mistake. `=` is assignment, you need to test for equality with `==`. But seriously, thanks for reviewing.

Comment: you can edit the question @Andras Deak you have more than 2000 rep :)

Comment: @AndrasDeak depends on the programming language.

Comment: @Glorfindel sorry, I wasn't being serious

Answer (score 41, accepted):

You can earn the Steward badge *once for every review queue*; it explicitly says so on [this page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/2279/steward?userid=5558072):

> This badge is awarded once per review type.

So you can earn at most 8 Steward badges on Stack Overflow (Documentation reviews don't count).

Comment: i see, i thought every 1000 review i can get a badge thank you for your answer @Glorfindel

Comment: I suspect Documentation reviews will reward badges once we figure out how to mitigate the impact of robo-reviewers.

Comment: @dorukayhan could be - note that there already is a Peer Review badge which corresponds to Custodian for normal reviews. We'll know in 6-8 weeks ...

Comment: Documentation started out with too much incentive and now has so little there no reason to contribute (unless its your good deed for the day)