# How does the system count the number of views?

Tags: support, questions, views

How does the system count the number of views of a post?

I know it is by every IP address, but does that happen once for every IP address per day, or per another period?

And how much is this period? 1 minute? 1 hour? Or how much exactly?

**EDIT**

After the answer below and the explanation [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/275046/number-of-views-on-question-getting-updated-on-refresh-just-a-coincidence/275049#275049) i think the system not work like that, because for example if enter to my post [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/338339/why-didnt-i-get-the-gold-badge-for-a-review-queue) i find the number is 863 and when i click again 3 times the number increase 3 times so the number now is 866?

Comment: *"when i click again 3 times the number increase 3 times"* Yeah, because 2 other people visited that question. There are a lot of people on Stack Overflow.

Comment: This not happen just one time it happen every time and 3 times exactly, if your comment is correct so maybe i can find 1 2 3 4 5 6 ...n viewer not 3 exact, i'm wrong?

Answer (score 2):

As explained [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/275049/4751173), it is 15 minutes.

> Views are tracked per IP address per rolling time window. If you come back to the question in, say, 15 minutes you'll see the counter go up by 1 again.

Note that the number of views is only tracked on *questions*, not answers.

Comment: thank you @Glorfindel but i think this is not true, because for example i enter to my post here http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/338339/why-didnt-i-get-the-gold-badge-for-a-review-queue: i find the number is 863 i clic again 3 times the number increase 3 times so the number now is 866?

Comment: Other people might have visited the question in the meantime; the number might be cached as well.

Comment: This happen every time not just one time, and it increase 3 time exactly!

Comment: @MrLY I just tried it on your question, but for me it stays on 867. I'm not sure if something like that exists, but you might have a very dynamic IP address (using Tor perhaps?)

Comment: Yes, i think this depends on the server you are using, maybe the company server and home server are not same, i'm wrong?

Comment: Of course, if you visit twice using different servers with different IP addresses, then it counts as two visits.

Comment: i'm sure that i'm using one server, not two